# Best way to sum up and visualize the relation between results of 2 tests measuring the same outcome with 3 results

Tags: distributions, roc, sensitivity-specificity, true-positive-rate

I have a dataset of different individuals who underwent 2 test that measure the same outcome with 3 possible results

1. not reduced
2. mildly reduced
3. highly reduced

I know that the distribution of the results of each test is different (highly significant).
What do you think is the best way to analyze and visualize the relation between the two test? Like, if Test 1 states "not reduced", how big is the chance that Test 2 says the same and is there any relationship at all or is it pure chance?